# Finding all edge types in a graph. Tree, Forward, Backward or Cross edges

Tags: graph, pseudocode, edges

I spent several hours looking for a pseudocode that would compute the edge types in a graph. I couldn't find a complete version so I wrote a new one. I will share it as a reply to this post, so others can reach it if needed.

Comment: You should rephrase your question as an actual question. And you should explain the code in your answer. This is not a forum. It's great that you want to add to SO's Q&A database, but make sure that you actually post questions and answers, not anecdotes and code dumps. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
edgeTypes(G, Source)
    time = 1
    Stack s
    for each(node in G.vertices)
        node.start = 0
        node.finish = 0

    s.push(Source)

    while(!s.isEmpty())
        node = s.peek()
        if(node.start > 0)
            node.finish = time++
            s.pop()
        else
            node.start = time++
            for each(neig in node.neighbors)
                if(neig.start == 0)
                    |node, neig|.type = 'tree'
                else if(neig.finish == 0)
                    |node, neig|.type = 'back'
                else if(node.start < neig.start)
                    |node, neig|.type = 'forward'
                else |node, neig|.type = 'cross'

                if(neig.start == 0)
                    s.push(neig)
```